# Mejor codigo en Python

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que dice asi:
Solicitar al usuario un número entero y luego un dígito. Informar la cantidad de ocurrencias del dígito en el número, utilizando para ello una función que calcule la frecuencia.

la respuesta a este codigo en la pagina de donde lo saque es esta:

```
      def frecuencia(numero,digito):
      cantidad=0
       while numero!=0:
       ultDigito=numero%10
       if ultDigito==digito:
       cantidad+=1
        numero=numero//10
       return cantidad


        num=int(input("Número: "))
        un_digito=int(input("Dígito: "))
         print("Frecuencia del dígito en el número:",frecuencia(num,un_digito))
```

sin embargo, yo lo resolvi asi y muestra lo mismo( aunque hay un error)

```
numeroEntero=int(input("ïntroduzca un numero entero: "))
digitoNumeroEntero=int(input("introduzca un digito: "))

x = [int(a) for a in str(numeroEntero)] #convierte a string el numero
print(x)

def ocurrencias(numeroEntero,digitoNumeroEntero):
    for digito in x:   #recorremos el numero entero en la lista
    if digito==digitoNumeroEntero:
        print(f'se encontro {x.count(digito)} veces el digito puesto')
    else:
        print(f'no se encontro ocurrencia del digito en el numero ')

 ocurrencias(numeroEntero,digitoNumeroEntero)
```

Mi duda es hay ventajas o desventajas con cada codigo?
cual seria la mejor practica?

Comment: Tienes 2 codigos diferentes que resuelven el problema. ¿Solo quieres saber cual conviene? ¿No vienes a resolver una problemática ni nada?

Comment: No tiene sentido hacer un ciclo si vas a ocupar `count`. Te habría bastado con el `print(f'se encontro ...`

Comment: si quiero solo saber cual conviene ya que estoy empezando y quiero aplicar buenas practicas @Excorpion

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que si vas a trabajar examinando digitos, te conviene mantener la información tal cual se ingresó, o sea, en formato string.

Una solución más pitonica (sin usar `count`) es crear una expresión generadora que retorne un '1' por cada digito que cumpla la condición, y luego sumar esos digitos:

```
cuenta = sum(1 for x in num if x == un_digito)
```

Una *expresión generadora* va retornado los elementos uno a uno; nunca construye la lista completa, como lo hace una `compresión de listas`.

#### Demo

```
num = input("Número: ")
un_digito = input("Dígito: ")
cuenta = sum(1 for x in num if x == un_digito)
print("Frecuencia del dígito en el número:", cuenta)
```

produce:

```
Número: 88993392213455634527934852709345780923847502134525
Dígito: 4
Frecuencia del dígito en el número: 6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: esta expresion generadora, hay tema al respecto? para ahondar mas

Comment: @anonymuus_gp. Google "python expresión generadora"